# create a huge text file in matlab with specific numbers?

Tags: matlab, text-files

How can I create a huge text file in matlab with millions of lines which contanin numbers 9876543210 and 5 emptyspace and again repeated numbers and 5 spaces for milions of lines?

```
myNumbers= (0:9);
fid = fopen('lastFile.txt','wt'); 
for i=1:99
fprintf(fid,'%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d \r',myNumbers); 
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: See: [Export to Text Data Files with Low-Level I/O](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/writing-to-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html)

Comment: @melif what have you tried so far?

Comment: myNumbers= (0:9);
fid = fopen('lastFile.txt','wt'); 
for i=1:99
fprintf(fid,'%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d \r',myNumbers); 
end
fclose(fid);

Comment: @willpowe2727 ....I posted the code i have tried but I do not know how to repate the code in one line and then going to to the next line repeating the same numbers and so one

Comment: How many times do you want the number/space sequence repeated for each line in file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loopy way:

```
myNumbers= (0:9);
repeats = 20;  %// number of times to repeat array on each line
lines = 99;    %// number of lines to write to file
fid = fopen('lastFile.txt','wt'); 
for n=1:lines
   for r=1:repeats
      fprintf(fid,'%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d     ',myNumbers); %// no return just yet
   end
   fprintf(fid, '\n'); %// or \r if that's what you really want
end
fclose(fid);
```

I changed the `\r` to `\n` because it made more sense to me. Unless you're using Mac OS 9. I also changed the one space at the end of the format specification to 5 spaces, since that's what you said you wanted.

To get the array to repeat on one line, you just have to make sure you don't add the newline until you've got everything you want on that line. Then do that for however many lines you want.

There are other ways to do this, but this is the most straightforward.